# Deprecation warning in PySide2

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use QApplication from PySide2.QtWidgets and in the console it gives warning about deprecation.

I tried to find the answer on google, but could not.

Here is the code:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

QApplication(sys.argv)
```

python: 3.7.3
PySide2: 5.12.1

I get this warning:

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
```

Comment: I had the same problem, because `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO` was set to `auto` in the system environment variables. Removing the variable (or setting it to an empty string) resolves the problem for me, but I have no idea why it was added in the first place.

Comment: Is this question answered in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194247/warning-qt-device-pixel-ratio-is-deprecated