# Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, opencv, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib alongside openCV to plot some thresholding methods and the following warning with no output is thrown:

> Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
>   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled
>   per-screen factors.    QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen
>   factors.    QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale
>   factor.

I am using Ubuntu 19.04

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('gradient.jpg', 0)

_, th1 = cv.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
_, th2 = cv.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, th3 = cv.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv.THRESH_TRUNC)
_, th4 = cv.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_TOZERO)
_, th5 = cv.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)

titles = ['Original Image', 'BINARY', 'BINARY_INV', 'TRUNC', 'TOZERO', 'TOZERO_INV']
images = [img, th1, th2, th3, th4, th5]

for i in range(6):
    plt.subplot(2, 3, i + 1), plt.imshow(images[i], 'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

Comment: Use `plt.show()` to show a matplotlib figure.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I'm still a noob. Any idea about the warnings?

Comment: An alternative method to show an image is to use `cv2.imshow()`. For example, `cv2.imshow('image', image[0])` followed by `cv2.waitKey()`

Comment: Concerning the warning, one would need to have more information about versions of python, matplotlib, cv, pyqt, and the system you run this on, as well as a self-contained example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you all. For me only [Elyte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61748904/3081830) did the trick. To use this in python, you could use:

```
from os import environ

def suppress_qt_warnings():
    environ["QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO"] = "0"
    environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    environ["QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS"] = "1"
    environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suppress_qt_warnings()
    
    # Init QT etc...
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by using the same method with @elyte5star.
Before Running the program, running following commands in your terminal:

```
export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=0
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```

Answer (score 4):

The warnings are about a change in the underlying Qt libraries:

> In Qt 5.4, there was an experimental implementation of high DPI scaling introduced via the QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO environment variable, that you could set to a numerical scale factor or auto. This variable was deprecated in Qt 5.6. ([source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt))

Since it's only a deprecation, I'm not sure that switching to the newer options will fix the problem of missing the output window. See the comments you got under your question for that.

But to get rid of the warnings, this should work in the shell when starting your script:

```
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1;
python myscript.py;
```

For details, see: [Qt Documentation: High DPI Displays](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html).

Answer (score 4):

Came across this solution!

```
    export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=0
    export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
    export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1
    export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting this while opening spyder from anaconda prompt. I solved it by deleting the QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO environment and system variables and restarted the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Simply You can Add **cv.waitkey(0)** at the end of the Code.