# when i try to run this code i have the following error :Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("cost_revenue_clean.csv")


X = DataFrame(data, columns = ['production_budget_usd'])
y = DataFrame(data, columns = ['worldwide_gross_usd'])

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.show
```

the error I have:

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
```

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194247/warning-qt-device-pixel-ratio-is-deprecated)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: QT\_DEVICE\_PIXEL\_RATIO is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194247/warning-qt-device-pixel-ratio-is-deprecated)